# Jmeter using cookie manager issue

Tags: jmeter

I have a form based authentication application I am able to log on the system as per my database by posting a request on my log in page. 

But after that if try a get request of any internal pages I get a request as `www.example\login?dashboard` with a cookie but the response html is of my login page.

I have a cookie manager added on the top.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple things to check that could be causing this:

1. There is a hardcoded parameter, like sessionID that needs to be unique for each session
2. The page requests have "automatic redirect" enabled and should not (or vice-versa)
3. Login is actually failing, but the site is not giving a clear error message